# Looking to add redirect url

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Below is an excerpt of code i'm running.

Up to this point the code searches for keywords in the URL, once it does it takes me here, the #add-to-cart is the actual add to cart button you would see on any online store.  So it clicks that and adds the item to the shopping cart, however, from there i need to get it to the shopping cart url to continue and i can't seem to figure out how to make it get to that URL

```
if(jQuery("#add-to-cart").length > 0)
        jQuery("#add-to-cart").trigger( "click" );
        if( window_href.match( new RegExp(/cart/) ) ){
         window.location.href = 'http://store.storeurl.com/cart';
}
```

maybe i need to remove this line, but that doesn't work either.

```
if( window_href.match( new RegExp(/cart/) ) )
```

Comment: You're supposed to use the `new RegExp` constructor with a string, not another regex. Also, what does clicking on that item do? The name suggests it might redirect the page, but the question doesn't specify if that's the case or not

Comment: Essentially, after it clicks the item i want and adds it to the shopping cart, i want to then have it go to the shopping cart url, which is where i'm running into my problem.  I've only attempted to code and learn for about a month now.

Comment: so after it clicks the #add-to-cart, is where i'm stuck, i want to send it to a new url.

Comment: Please elaborate on this in the question, not the comments, unless you're sure it's not a problem: "Also, what does clicking on that item [`#add-to-cart`] do?" The name suggests that it redirects the browser page, but there's not enough information about this

Comment: elaborated. thanks for the swift replies all.

Comment: @blgt you can use a regex in the constructor of RegExp. I tried it, works fine.  It might not be the most efficient, but it's not causing his problem.

Comment: @Paul I know, thus a comment and not an answer. I think we can agree it's bad form though

Answer (score 1):

SO there are several things that could be happening here, depending on the state of the page in question.

The most likely thing, based on what you're describing, is that the `window_href` variable doesn't actually have a value in it that matches 'cart'.  Can you console that value out before the test in order to find out?

Also, using the `.trigger()` method may or may not be synchronous, so if you do get the redirect working you might discover that the trigger handler doesn't have time to finish firing before the page gets reloaded. You might want to have the handler call the redirect, rather than calling it as the next statement as you have done.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I will get on that shortly with a reply.